# Como obtener el subtotal del group footer

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

estoy trabajando en Visual Studio 2013 y DevExpress

Con este código obtengo el total de los dos pie de grupo mi pregunta es como obtener el total de uno de los pie de grupo

```
My.Forms.frmDev.TxtMonto.EditValue = (V_Quincena.Columns("Total").SummaryItem.SummaryValue)
My.Forms.frmDev.TxtMonto.EditValue = (V_Quincena.Columns("Total").SummaryItem.SummaryValue)
```

¿cómo obtengo el subtotal de ese *gruop footer*?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia, pero eso de group footer es para imprimir reportes?

Comment: Hola José. Tu pregunta no es clara ya que la etiqueta dice que se trata de VB.NET, pero no has compartido ningún código. Te sugiero de leer: [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: TwoDent eso es un pie de grupo que esta una de la propiedad del grid que tiene devExpress

Comment: Con este codigo obtengo el total de los dos pie de grupo mi pregunta es como obtener el total de uno de los pie de grupo My.Forms.frmDev.TxtMonto.EditValue = (V_Quincena.Columns("Total").SummaryItem.SummaryValue)

Comment: Como dice sstan, monta el codigo para que se te ayude mejor.

Comment: ¿Has intentado recorrer esa columna usando un For Each In?... como el valor que deseas sacar esta en la misma columna "Total"... o mas facil, podrias buscar la manera de acceder directamente a una celda (que me imagino que lo hay) de esa columna... y si te pide por el index de la celda, puedes contar de 0 desde la primera celda. Te daria una respuesta elaborada pero es que yo nunca he trabjado con ese control.